# I want to use localStorage to save some data which is entered by the user so I can display the information back in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json

So I am building a restaurant ordering system for some practice, the user chooses a waiter and adds an order or comment to the selected waiter.

This is then pushed to the Waiter object using the methods created.

I want to store the data which is imputed by the user, so it can be viewed in the console after the page is reloaded.

I want to accomplish this using JSON not PHP/other.

So when I reopen the the page any data pushed to the arrays are still visible when logged to the console.

Any links or code would be very appreciated

/*

```
//Waiters Section

*/


//Waiter Constructor
class Waiter {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.order = [];
        this.total = 0;
        this.comment = [];
    }


    //Methods to map() the price argument
    //and then reduce() to get the total  
    addFood(item) {
        this.order.push(item);
        this.total = this.order
            .map(o => o.price, 0)
            .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    };


    //Method to push any comments to the selected waiter
    addComment(c){
        this.comment.push(c) + " ";      
    }


};





//Array to store waiters
const waiters = [
    new Waiter('Timo'),
    new Waiter('Lucian'),
    new Waiter('Arpi')

];





//Adding the waiters to the options menu
const waitersEl = document.getElementById('waiters');
waiters.forEach(({
    name
}) => waitersEl.options.add(new Option(name)));





/*

//Food Section Main

*/

//Food Constructor
class Item {
    constructor(item, price) {
        this.item = item;
        this.price = price;
        this.label = `${item} (${price})`;
    }
}



//Main food array
const mainFood = [
    new Item('Peene Primvera', 14),
    new Item("Lasagne", 14),
    new Item("Fillet Steak", 20)
];






//Addin the options for each food and price item inside the dropdown menu
const foodMain = document.getElementById('menuMain');
mainFood.forEach(({
    label,
    item
}, index) => foodMain.options.add(new Option(label, index)));




/*

//Fucntion for when the form is submited it adds the  

*/
const formEl = document.getElementById('mainForm');

formEl.onsubmit = function (e) {

    //Selecting the comment input on the form to pass to the 
    //comment waiters array.
    const comment = document.getElementById('comment').value;


    //Selecting the choosen index from the user food and which waiter orderd //it which waiter.
    //Selects the choosen food to pass to the addFood method in the waiter //class.
    const foodItemIndex = foodMain.options[foodMain.selectedIndex].value;
    const foodItem = mainFood[foodItemIndex];


    //Selecting the waiter to push valid informaiton to.
    const waiterName = waitersEl.options[waitersEl.selectedIndex].value;
    const waiter = waiters.find(({name}) => name === waiterName);


    //Logic to check when submited if both feilds are true proceed.
    //The statements check to see which feild values have been entered
    //Then it call's the corresponding method from the waiter class and
    //pushes the value to the choosen array
    if (waiter && foodItem && comment) {
        waiter.addFood(foodItem)
        waiter.addComment(comment);
        console.log(waiters);
    }
    else if (waiter && comment) {
        waiter.addComment(comment);
        console.log(waiters);        
    }
    else if (waiter && foodItem){    
        waiter.addFood(foodItem)
        console.log(waiters);
    }




    formEl.reset();  
    return false; // prevents redirect/refresh

};
```

After the form has been submitted once:

```
0: Waiter
comment: ["This form has been submitted I will now close the window and when I reopen I will not be here"]
name: "Timo"
order: [Item]
total: 14
```

Now when I reopen:

```
0: Waiter
comment: []
name: "Timo"
order: []
total: 0
```

I want it so when I reopen the data is still inside the array.

Comment: **Any links or code would be very appreciated** - This is not a coding service. Show what you attempted and what is the issue/error with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After form submission, you write to localStorage using localStorage.setItem(key,value);

OnSubmit of the form: push each WaiterObject to an array of items and then save items array to localStorage

using localStorage.getItem() method retrieve the value from localStorage and set to items  and display the items,

here is an example of storing and retrieve logic explained above

```
https://coderwall.com/p/ewxn9g/storing-and-retrieving-objects-with-localstorage-html5
```

Answer (score -1):

You could perform 
`localStorage.setItem('waiters', JSON.stringify(waiters))`
when any update is made.

Then before `waiters` creation check if 
`localStorage.getItem('waiters', JSON.stringify(waiters))`
exists and use it instead of creation.